# Azure AD B2C MFA and remember device

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

How to login with MFA to a AZURE AD B2C App using the login url(URL given below) provided by microsoft?

Do we have any URL to validate users login with MFA Azure AD B2C?

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Comment: What is your redirect URL? you can login with redirect url,  it should be something like this https://your-B2C-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-B2C-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp. if in case if you want To get a token from the Azure AD endpoint, you need to define the protocols that Azure AD B2C should use to communicate with Azure AD. This is done inside the TechnicalProfile element of ClaimsProvider.

Answer (score 0):

That URL is only part of the flow.

The whole flow is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect).

The easiest way to achieve this is to use one of the [MSAL libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/integrate-with-app-code-samples).

MFA is not part of the OpenID Connect flow.

You have to [add it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).